# Which Is Better .....mysql or mysqli or PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

I have just started PHP and mysql . I have Come through different functions of Mysql and Mysqli . I have also heard about PDO . Now i want to know which will be better one than the others and why ???

Comment: `mysql_*`: do not use. The others: up to you.

Answer (score 2):

This site isn't really for "what's best" type questions.

In short, don't use mysql (obviously, the PHP docs have warnings on every page!).  It is no longer enabled by in recent versions of PHP, see here for more information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Do use mysqli or PDO, depending on which you fancy. PDO lets you use more than just mysql and creates a standard interface for switching in and out different database drivers.  It is considered "the best" by many due to its flexibility, but of course that is a meaningless statement without qualification of what the best is!

Evaluate your needs and compare the two from there.